# Need to delete file in js application but got /fakepath

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, path

I have a javascript/java application for uploading file to a server; due to HTML5 security spec I get C:\fakepath\file_name
My problem is that after uploading I have to delete the local file, so I need the actual path, otherwise I get "file not found" error.
I don't need to display path in chrome, just using it for deleting.
The application originally worked with internet explorer and activex, with which it was possible to resolve the fakepath, but we have to migrate to chrome and remove activex.

Is there a way to know the actual path in chrome?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: "Is there a way to know the actual path in chrome? — No, and if there was then there still wouldn't be an API that would let you delete the file. Maybe you should be writing an Electron-based app instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Originally, deleting was managed by calling a c# function passing path as parameter; I hoped I can reuse it, but if there's no way to get the actual path I deduce I have to abandon the idea.